# Record-replay tools for Windows?

Tags: windows, binary-analysis, x86, tools

Are there any user-mode record-replay tools for Windows that can capture native execution of a program so that it can be replayed deterministically later? Instructions, memory accesses, syscalls and so on. I tried PinPlay but the overhead was too much.

Comment: This is a complex task, which requires a complex tool. I'm unaware of any other tool that performs that task. Would be interested in hearing of such tools! +1